# SAS - compare two datasets by 1 to 5 non-unique key variables to flag missings and differences?

Tags: compare, combinations

I am looking to compare two SAS datasets. They can be compared by up to 5 'key' variables which are sometimes not unique. If I were to do this by several separate merges this would be

- merge by VarA
- merge by VarB
- merge by VarA and Var B
- merge by VarC
- merge by VarA and VarC
- merge by VarA, VarB, and VarC etc (every combination from 1 to 5 variables = 35 combinations).

For each comparison I would need to:-

- sort and dedupe each of the two datasets by the merge variable(s)
- merge by the merge variable
- merge the matching records back to the original datasets by the merge var in question (to get every instance of it) to check each other variable for value difference or missings
- repeat for all 35 merge var combinations.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Obviously may take a while to run!

Possibly concatenate all the unique lists then do one merge with different flags for different combos of missing or different?

I can do this with many datasteps individually, but I've not found a way to rerun on all combinations of a 5 variable key using 1, 2... 5 variables. Is there a sas 'combination' function?

I could create a macro run 35 times, each call being a different merge key combo?